# extract in same column cell with different format

Tags: microsoft-excel, date, extract

I need to extract value in same column that have different format (date and text) as showed below:

```
09/02/80
23/12/73
ANA
ANA
11/03/83
11/03/83
07/07/34
```

How could obtain from one column two separated columns, one with all date and the other with only text?
Thanks in advance

Comment: do you mean get from one column or get from one row?

Answer (score 1):

In **B1** enter:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A1),A1,"")
```

and copy down.  In **C1** enter:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A1),"",A1)
```

and copy down:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select the column with the mixed data. Press Ctrl + C, to copy the cells. Move to and adjacent cell that has enough blank cells to copy without pasting values over important data.

Next: Your selected cell should be where you want your data to be pasted into place.

Next: Press Alt, then E, then S (This is paste-special shortcut). 
Next: Under "Paste", select radio button "Formulas and number formats"
--- also under "Operation", select radio button "Add".

Next: Click OK.
The cells adjacent to your data should only be numbers and dates as expected.

[Image of instructions link.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvUZ0.png)